# AJAX + Promises: Chaining AJAX calls not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, promise

I'm trying to make a `POST` (technically a `DELETE`) request to a `php` page (`delete_post.ajax.php`), which takes the data from my `AJAX` call, and uses that to remove an item from my database. Afterwards, I want my `AJAX` to make a `GET` request to another page (`api/blog.php`) that queries the database for the rest of the items in that table.

So far I am able to `DELETE` the items from the database, but when chaining on `.then()` it does not chain like I would expect it to.

If I visit `...api/blog.php`, the page returns valid `JSON` as expected.

### JS AJAX

```
const deletePostBtn = document.querySelectorAll('button[name="delete_post"]');

// GET REQUEST TO RETRIEVE EVERY POST
const get = (url) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.open('GET', url, true);

    xhttp.onload = () => {
      if (xhttp.status == 200) {
        resolve(JSON.parse(xhttp.response));
      } else {
        reject(xhttp.statusText);
      }
    };

    xhttp.onerror = () => {
      reject(xhttp.statusText);
    };

    xhttp.send();
  });
}

// DELETE SPECIFIC POST
const deletePostPromise = (url, postID) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('POST', url, true);

    xhr.onload = () => {
      if (xhr.status == 200) {
        console.log('if (xhr.status == 200)');
      } else {
        reject(xhr.statusText);
      }
    };

    xhr.onerror = () => {
      reject(xhr.statusText);
    };

    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    // console.log(`About to SEND ${postID}`);
    xhr.send(postID);
    // console.log(`Just SENT ${postID}`);
  });
}

// MAKING THE CALL TO DELETE THE POST
if (deletePostBtn) {
  for (let i = 0; i < deletePostBtn.length; i++) {
    deletePostBtn[i].addEventListener('click', e => {
      e.preventDefault();

      const displayPostSection = document.querySelector('.col-8.pt-4');
      const postID = document.querySelectorAll('#delete-post-id');

      deletePostPromise('http://localhost/mouthblog/ajax/delete_post.ajax.php', `id=${postID[i].value}`)
        .then(() => {
          console.log('DOES NOT MAKE IT TO THIS console.log');
        })
        .then(() => {
          get('http://localhost/mouthblog/api/blog.php')
            .then(data => {
              console.log(data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.log(error);
            });
        });
    });
  }
}
```

### delete_post.ajax.php (page submitted to delete post)

```
<?php

  include('../includes/db/connection.php');
  include('../includes/db/delete/delete_post.query.php');

  $delete_post = new DeletePost($_POST['id']);
```

### include('../includes/db/delete/delete_post.query.php');

```
<?php

class DeletePost extends Connection {
  public function __construct($id) {
    $this->connect();

    $sql = "DELETE FROM `posts`
            WHERE `id`=:id";
    $query = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
    $result = $query->execute(
      [
        ':id' => htmlentities($id, ENT_QUOTES, 'ISO-8859-15'),
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

### /api/blog.php (this is where my `JSON` comes from, returns all post data)

```
<?php

  include('../includes/db/connection.php');
  include('../includes/db/read/blog_roll.query.php');
  $get_data = new BlogRoll;
```

### include('../includes/db/read/blog_roll.query.php');

```
<?php

class BlogRoll extends Connection {
  public function __construct() {
    $this->connect();

    $sql    = "SELECT `id`, `user_id`, `user_name`, `content`, `date_created`
               FROM `posts`
               ORDER BY `date_created` DESC";
    $query  = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
    $result = $query->execute();

    if ($result) {
      $returnArray = [];

      while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        array_push($returnArray, $row);
      }

      header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8');
      exit(json_encode($returnArray));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `deletePostPromise`: Inside `xhr.onerror` you call `reject()` but you never call `resolve()` (which I'd expect you to do inside `xhr.onload`).

`then` will only do something if you resolve or reject the promise. Since there isn't an error, it doesn't get rejected, and there is no condition in which it would be resolved.

(You did resolve it for `get`).

Comment: Going through the `MOZ DEV` docs, I don't think I completely understand `resolve()`. In my `get` call, you can see I'm giving it the `xhr.response`. Now in my `POST` I'm not passing anything and it's working. Should I pass anything in my `POST` as well or will it be fine if I leave it empty?

Comment: What you pass to `resolve` gets passed to the function you pass to `then`. If you want to pass data out of the promise, that's the usual way to do it. Your code isn't *expecting* any data there.

Answer (score 0):

Briefly reading the code, I don't see any resolve() function in deletePostPromise(). So, you are only returning from the Promise when you get error in the REST call.